# How should I integrate a go library in a flutter app ? platform channels ? Pigeon ? FFI?

Tags: flutter, go, native

I have a go library with around 100 functions and around 40 struct types.
It's mostly interacting with structs and byte arrays.
I would like to build a multi platform app (android/ios/windows/linux) using flutter.
My first port would be the Android app.

-- edit --
I don't really need callbacks from native code to Dart.
My structs do contain nested structs and arrays of structs
-- edit --

I created bindings with gomobile and have my lib.aar for Android.
From the flutter documentation, it seems to me that there are 3 different methods for doing that :

- platform channels, lots of code to write ?
- pigeon, automatic code generation, but a lot of code to write anyway ?
- FFI ?

What is the best/fastest/painless method ? 
I would have expected that generating interface code from java classes or go code, would be more or less automatic but it seems not possible.

Do you know where can I could find complete examples, not just basic a+b ?

Thank you

Comment: It really all depends on whether ffi supports all the types you need to pass - and whether you ever need to call from native->Dart (spoiler - that's much harder in ffi)

Comment: I don't really need callbacks. However I got quite complex structs and collections as parameters, or return values. And I see now, that gomobile already silently skipped some of them, still a long way forward ! :D

Comment: If you want real examples, look in pub, e.g. https://pub.dev/packages?q=dependency%3Affi in particular win32 or sodium Similarly look for packages that depend on pigeon. For normal method channel examples there are so many that you can probably find every possible use case just in the core ones https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/main/packages

Comment: Honestly, you'll have to try all the methods and gauge the effort for yourself. All options probably fall into two buckets: hard and impossible :) At least then you can rule out the impossible ones.